# Custom Attribute For Class Library Classes and Functions in C#

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, attributes, class-library

I'm developing 3rd party API connector bridge in class library **NOT** in ASP.NET.

**User Levels**

API has 3 user levels, lets say:

- UserGoer
- UserDoer
- UserMaker

**Service Restriction**

Each API operation can work with one or multiple user level roles. For example, lets assume operations and reachable user levels as follows;

- JokerService (reachable by UserGoer, UserMaker)
- PokerService (reachable by UserGoer, UserDoer)
- MokerService (reachable by UserGoer, UserDoer, UserMaker)

If UserDoer requests for JokerService, API returns bad request. JokerService is only reachable for UserGoer and UserMaker. So, I want to restrict and throw an exception.

**User Token Structure**

```
public interface IToken
{
    string AccessToken { get; set; }

    string RefreshToken { get; set; }
}

public class AuthenticationToken : IToken
{
    [JsonProperty("access_token")]
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("refresh_token")]
    public string RefreshToken { get; set; }
}


public class UserGoerAuthenticationToken : AuthenticationToken
{
}

public class UserDoerAuthenticationToken : AuthenticationToken
{
}

public class UserMakerAuthenticationToken : AuthenticationToken
{
}
```

**Enum**

```
public enum TokenType
{
    Undefined = 0,
    UserGoer = 1,
    UserDoer = 2,
    UserMaker = 3
}
```

**Customized Authentication Attribute**

```
public class AuthenticationFilter : Attribute
{
    public TokenType[] TokenTypes { get; private set; }

    public AuthenticationFilter(params TokenType[] TokenTypes)
    {
        this.TokenTypes = TokenTypes;
    }
}
```

**Example Service**

```
[AuthenticationFilter(TokenType.UserGoer, TokenType.UserMaker)]
internal class JokerService : BaseService<JokerEntity>
{
    public JokerService(IToken AuthenticationToken) : base(AuthenticationToken)
    {
        var tokenTypes = 
              (typeof(JokerService).GetCustomAttributes(true)[0] as AuthenticationFilter)
              .TokenTypes;

        bool throwExceptionFlag = true;
        foreach (var item in tokenTypes)
        {
            // Check AuthenticationToken is UserGoer or UserMaker by StartsWith function
            if (AuthenticationToken.GetType().Name.StartsWith(item.ToString()))
            {
                throwExceptionFlag = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (throwExceptionFlag)
            throw new Exception("Invalid Authentication Token");
    }

    public JokerEntity Create(RequestModel<JokerEntity> model) => base.Create(model);

    public JokerEntity Update(RequestModel<JokerEntity> model) => base.Update(model);

    public JokerEntity Get(RequestModel<JokerEntity> model) => base.Get(model);

    public List<JokerEntity> List(RequestModel<JokerEntity> model) => base.List(model);
}
```

In summary, JokerService can be executable by UserGoer and UserMaker. UserDoer has no permission for this service.

As you see the the usage of `AuthenticationFilter` attribute, I'm getting custom attributes in  the constructor, because i want to know what `IToken` is. If there is an irrelevant "User Authentication Token" type that is passed as parameter (IToken), program should be throw an exception.

This is my solution, do you think is there any best practice for my problem?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. My initial thought at constructive critique would be that the tokens accepted by a particular class via the attribute is something decided at compile time and is unable to change. But, the checking for permissions is happening on the construction of each object.

You can prevent this with a `static` constructor that sets the `tokenTypes` variable. Static constructors always run before instance constructors. This is also a good place to ensure that `tokenTypes` is never null (in the absence of your custom attribute).

Likewise, the looping through `tokenTypes` can probably be a function that takes in an `IToken` and the `tokenTypes`, and more importantly, could probably live in the BaseService.cs. Writing that logic once will make it easier to maintain when some future requirement necessitates its change. :)

See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, after I asked the question, I moved tokenType checking parts to the BaseService.cs :)
Static constructor would be ok for us. However, we want to use attribute. Attribute marking will always setup above all class. Because, every operation requires at least one user role.

Comment: @FatihTAN Right. You should keep the attribute. The act of finding the attribute uses reflection on the type - something that can be done in a static ctor or function.

Comment: Alright, thank you. I can write static ctor. Actually, it is not asked in the question but, one more thing i want to ask: how about method filter. For instance, think about class is not marked with Attribute. Only methods are marked. Lets's assume; UserGoer and UserDoer can reach Create method, but UserMaker doesn't. How can I check when I call the function.

Comment: @FatihTAN Having the attributes on the methods would be slightly more complicated. You might need a dictionary of method names and permissions. This could also be handled in the static ctor, but like I said, would be a bit more effort.

Comment: When I include static ctor, I cannot pass the IToken. Thus, I prefer object constructor.